# finding solutions to equations in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all solutions to the equation x2 + 3x + 2 = 0 in the ring Z16 [x].

I don't know how to find solutions to quadratic equations in rings.  Can someone help me get started?

Comment: Since there are only 16 candidates, you could at least try them all!

Comment: Do you want solutions *in the polynomial ring* over $\;\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z\;$ or on $\;\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
$$ x^2 + 3x + 2 =(x+1)(x+2) $$

and try to find necessary condition so that $16$ divides $(x+1)(x+2)$

Comment: so when x=14? since x=14 gives 240 and 240 is divisible by 16.  Then what does that mean exactly in terms of an answer

Comment: I assumed that you want to solve $x^2+3x+2=0$ in the ring $\mathbb Z_{16}$, so you have to find all elements $x\in \mathbb Z_{16}$ such that the equation holds, $x=14$ is one of the solutions you have to find the others using the hint